# Is there a Software-Center (like in Ubuntu) in Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management

I wondered if there is some easy to use Software-Center in Debian as well. (You can search and install software easily with it.)

[image]

**Software Center**

The program can be used to add and manage repositories as well as Ubuntu Personal Package Archives (PPA) and on Ubuntu, the Ubuntu Software Center also allows users to purchase commercial applications.

Comment: It might help if you described what a Software Center is, for people who don't use Ubuntu.

Comment: `synaptic` , but synaptic doesn't have offer.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh What do you mean, offer?

Comment: in your application, your application has some offer in category, but synaptic doesn't this feature.

Comment: Of course i suggest you use, apt-get command, dpkg , apt-cache and apt-file, it's very better than a GUI application.

Comment: I did'nt get any of the comments but here is more specfik info about deb and ubuntu; https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Debian_vs_Ubuntu

Comment: no, it's not "way better" than any GUI application as they don't show screenshots, or tabs to click to easily peruse install options, dependencies etc. On top of that the GUIs use the same underlying tools. Streuth,

Answer (score 2):

There is a version of Software Center in Debian 7:
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/software-center
However, it does not offer commercial software.

That package is not available in Debian Testing or Sid. Interestingly, the Gnome package "Software", which is the same kind of gui affair is marked as being "not in Debian" for Gnome 3.12.

Comment: will this work only under Gnome or also under other DEs?

Comment: Gnome Software is specific to Gnome (but not included in Debian). Software Center is available in Debian 6 for all DEs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems not behind Ubuntu then.

Answer (score 1):

Software Center like, as GUI package manager, you can use packagekit or synaptic. They don't use many graphics effects, as USC does, but it should be a GUI equivalent of the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

The principal desktop environments, as GNOME and KDE, use to be its own Software Center.

Gnome includes Gnome Software, KDE includes your own (I don't know the name)

In Debian Testing I use Gnome Software without problem

Answer (score 1):

After installing Debian 10.3 Buster with the gnome deskop on a friends machine, the 'software center' was there. On my own machine I just also installed Debian 10.3 with the Cinnamon desktop, but there was no software center. I added it with

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

and it needed a restart till it was there. So whether it is there or not depends on which desktop you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Add Remove Software seems to be the equivalent in 7.8.Move the mouse cursor to the top-left corner, click on 'Applications' after it pops up and start typing it in

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Debian UnStable and I have a software package that comes with Gnome.I prefer Synaptic (when using a GUI) though, as it's a mature product. I wasn't too pleased with 'software center' as it now stands.